# ethernet cable auto-negociation at 100mbps on some devices

Tags: networking, router, ethernet

I recently installed one cat6 cable, Cable is working, meanwhile in 2 of 3 devices, the auto negotiation is set to 100mbps, i was able to manually force to gigabit on one of them with success, i did not try on the other.

I tried a RJ-45 cable tester and all the 8 wires gave a green light, all terminations are set to T-568A

Is this still a cable issue ?

Edit: cable tested at one device at the time, all ports are gigabit capable, seems to me a negotiation issue, probably with the NIC's

Edit2 : it's probably solved, i crimped again but this time with TA-568B, cable tester gave ok once again and i got a successful auto-negotiation on one of the devices that didn't worked before. I got to test on the other one that i can't test now.

Comment: How exactly is one cable connected to 3 devices?

Comment: one at the time

Comment: Are all the devices ethernet ports capable of gigabit speed? If they arent then you will only have 100 mbits speed connection.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: All ports are gigabit

Comment: Is it  ready-to-use cable that you purchased or did you or someone crimp CAT6 cable as a patch cable? I have seen some cheap readymade cables that sometimes don't give 1Gbps and sometimes even a small loose contact during crimping results into speed falling back to 100Mbps even though basic LAN tester shows all connected.

Comment: it's probably solved, i crimped again but this time with TA-568B, cable tester gave ok once again and i got a successful auto-negotiation on one of the devices that didn't worked before. I got to test on the other one that i can't test now. Thanks you all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's probably solved, i crimped again but this time with TA-568B, cable tester gave ok once again and i got a successful auto-negotiation on one of the devices that didn't worked before. I got to test on the other one that i can't test now.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).